# Word 2013: Disabling spellcheck for following-typed words, then reenabling for ones after

Tags: microsoft-word, macros, microsoft-word-2013

I have 2 macros, one that switches to Courier New and one that switches to Calibri. I use these to write a few lines of code in between and as part of regular paragraphs. The font change helps distinguish them, but spell-check still underlines code snippets as incorrect.

Is there a way to temporarily disable spellcheck, type some characters, then reenable spellcheck, but exclude those typed characters from the check?

e.g. paragraphs

> zugzug
>
> `{enter code format macro}`
>
> `dabu`
>
> `{exit code format macro}`
>
> zugzug

e.g. inline

> zugzug `{enter code format} dabu {exit code format}` zugzug

In the above examples, `dabu` should **not** be underlined as an incorrectly spelled word.

[Word: Disable spell checker for a paragraph?](https://superuser.com/questions/256247/word-disable-spell-checker-for-a-paragraph) is similar, but it covers a way to disable spell-check for a highlighted section.

Answer (score 2):

First, select the text for which you want to ignore spelling in your document.

Right click and select Styles > Save selection as a new Quick Style. Then click on Modify and a new window will open named "Create new style from Formatting". Set your font type, font size etc. and then click on the Format button which stands on the lower left corner of the window. Select Language option and check "Do not check spelling or grammar" option. Click OK, and OK again.

Now you have a style which will not check spelling or grammar for the font style you determined.

Comment: This is fantastic. Thank you! The only thing is changing the style changes the entire paragraph's style. So with this method, code that's inline with with a paragraph must be written in the regular font, then highlighted, then style-switched to the code style. That and it looks like styles don't play nice when applied to lists or other formats than plain paragraphs. Is there a way around this?

Comment: Did you check the "Add to template" check box when making this new style?

Comment: I can't see that option. Should have mentioned that I'm using Word 2013. Similar options are "Add to Styles Gallery" (no effect) and "New Document based on this template" (no effect). Which window is this check box in?

Comment: You're fine. In the lower left hand corner of the new style window that box that we selected language in you can select paragraph and set the paragraph styles and list styles. Give that a try messing with those settings and matching them with the settings that you are already using for the regular style.

Comment: Thanks for your help. The styles method seems to be good if you're working with separate code blocks on their own paragraphs, but inline styles still seem to be a problem. It also doesn't seem to be possible to set it to work with lists, tables, and paragraphs at the same time, unlike the font switching method.

Comment: Well, if you see the styles window that you can change between styles that have been added to the quick styles gallery. Try modifying one of the styles that works with your already used style for the normal text, and change the font to Calibri and select the same option in the language category, which should do the trick for you. I just did it on my machine (2013 word win 7 x64bit).